# I'll be too busy looking good

Tags: meaning, sentence-meaning

This the famous script from the movie Enter the Dragon.

Han:

> We are all ready to win, just as we are born knowing only life. It is defeat that you must learn to prepare for.

Williams:

> I Don't waste my time with it. When it comes, I won't even notice.

Han:

> Oh? How so?

Williams:

> I'll be too busy looking good.

I did not understand the last line. What does Williams  mean by saying *busy looking good*?

Comment: To be too busy [doing something]. It's always slightly sarcastic. If you are too busy [doing something], you don't have time to do whatever the other person says or wants.

Comment: It's a rather "facetious" usage, because *looking good* is normally a relatively "passive" action, so you wouldn't usually be ***busy*** doing it. But Williams just means he expects to be strutting and crowing over his ***victory*** (since he doesn't expect to be defeated, he's not interested in ***preparing*** for that possible outcome). Or maybe he's so obsessed with "looking good" that he won't be distracted from doing that even if he ***is*** defeated. You can make up your own mind on that score.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica would it be an option for you to convert your comment to an actual answer?

Comment: @Anatolii: Not really, because I've voted to close *for lack of research*. It should be no problem for learners to understand the meaning of each individual ***word*** as spoken by Williams, which to my mind makes it trivial to extrapolate the *overall meaning* (though as I pointed out, *in practice* there's scope for at least a couple of rather different implications). But these are matters of "situational interpretation", and I'd expect anyone actually following the movie to be able to select the most likely of the two possibilities I gave above. That's just common sense, not *language*.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica To me, for whom English is a foreign language the question sounds interesting. Additionally, understanding each individual **word** is not always sufficient to extrapolate the overall *meaning*.  Nevertheless, I accept that you may disagree with that.

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica You know the usage is "facetious." You know the phrasing is "slightly sarcastic." You know it's a matter of "situational interpretation" with at least a "couple of  interpretations." And you still think that English language learners should have no trouble understanding the line if they researched the meaning of each word? Wow.

Comment: @Anatolii: I wouldn't make a big deal of it. And after all, since you ***are*** a "learner" yourself, you should probably have a better idea than me of what constitutes a "good" question here on ELL. If you find anything useful in my comments, feel free to copy it into an answer of your own (ditto as regards Lambie's comments; I'm sure he'd be quite happy to be "plagiarised" in that way too). Note that I *haven't* seen the quote *in context*. But surely the OP has, so that should more than make up for my ability to *guess* exactly what Williams "meant".

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica Tsk, tsk, tsk. I'm a she. :) That said: One can be too busy [doing anything at all!] This is a **cliché** in English in response to someone else's comment(s).

Comment: @FumbleFingersReinstateMonica: I did my research before posting the question here. I knew the meaning of each individual word in the phrase. It was the meaning of the words in altogether I find difficult to understand. Your comment was a bit discouraging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a rather "facetious" usage, because looking good is normally a relatively "passive" action, so you wouldn't usually be busy doing it. But Williams just means he expects to be strutting and crowing over his victory (since he doesn't expect to be defeated, he's not interested in preparing for that possible outcome). Or maybe he's so obsessed with "looking good" that he won't be distracted from doing that even if he is defeated. You can make up your own mind on that score.

– Comment of FumbleFingers Reinstate Monica.